# Pattern Searching Grep

Tags: linux, grep, pattern-matching

i know there are alot of answers out there - but I am yet to find one which answers my question:

Hopefully someone can help!

I have a configuration file which is laid out like so:

```
define name{
            name        Stephen
            URL:        www.stephen.com
}
define name {
            name        Bob
            URL:        
}
```

What I need to do using grep is to search this file - and if URL is blank then return the name - in the above instance, it would return Bob.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -B1 'URL:[ ]*$'|grep -oP '[ ]*name[ ]*\K.*'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, can you explain this to me please? '[ ]*name[ ]*\K.*'

Comment: @McCourt2364 see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind#t=201610270225305411655